# Neat UX Trick Not working. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, user-experience

**Question**

The Commented code at the top of the javascript is my attempt to make it so that the relevant chosen button tab (on the nav bar changes color, gets a background etc). But when I uncomment the code at the top, not only does it not work, but the hamburger menu stops working too!

How can I adjust it to make the class work (so that the selected tab is made obvious to the user)?

**My Code**

```js
//Nav Bar!!

//Button selected gets color change

/*
const selectedNav = document.querySelectorAll('li');

selectedNav.forEach((item)=>{
    document.selectedNav.addEventListener('click', navChange)
})

function navChange(event){
    ul.forEach((item)=>{
        item.classList.remove('add-this-to-selected-section');
    })
    event.target.classList.add('add-this-to-selected-section');
}
*/

const navSlide = () =>{
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

// Toggle Nav
    burger.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');


    //Animate Links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index)=>{
        if(link.style.animation){
            link.style.animation = '';
        } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`
        }
   
    })
    //Burger Animation

    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');

})

}

navSlide();
```

```css
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}


.nav-links{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 50%;
}

.nav-links li{
   list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a{
    color: #245871;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.add-this-to-selected-section{
    color: white;
    background-color: #245871;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.burger div{
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #245871;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.burger{
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1024){
    .nav-links{
        width: 70%;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: 1200;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 997px){
   body{
       overflow-x: hidden;
   }
   
   nav{
       color: white;
   }

   .head-btn{
       color: white;
   }

    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: #245871;
        color: white;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 70%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }

    .nav-links a{
        opacity: 1;
        color: white;
    }
    .burger{
      display: block;
    }
}

.nav-active{
    transform: translateX(0%);
    color: white;
}

@keyframes navLinkFade{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    } to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
                    <h4>xxx</h4>    
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li class=".home-btn"><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
                <li class=".exchange-btn"><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
                <li class=".debit-btn"><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
                <li class=".crypto-btn"><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
                <li class=".stock-btn"><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="burger">    
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>

            </div>
```

Your help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background color for that class was the same, and also your javascript for that functionality had some problems. Here's how it should be:

```js
const selectedNav = document.querySelectorAll('li');

const navChange = (index) => {
    selectedNav.forEach((item)=>{
        item.classList.remove('add-this-to-selected-section');
    })
    selectedNav[index].classList.add('add-this-to-selected-section');
}


selectedNav.forEach((item, index)=>{
    item.addEventListener('click', ()=> navChange(index))
})



const navSlide = () =>{
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

// Toggle Nav
    burger.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');


    //Animate Links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index)=>{
        if(link.style.animation){
            link.style.animation = '';
        } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`
        }
   
    })
    //Burger Animation

    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');

})

}

navSlide();
```

```css
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}


.nav-links{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 50%;
}

.nav-links li{
   list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a{
    color: #245871;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.add-this-to-selected-section{
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.burger div{
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #245871;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.burger{
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1024){
    .nav-links{
        width: 70%;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: 1200;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 997px){
   body{
       overflow-x: hidden;
   }
   
   nav{
       color: white;
   }

   .head-btn{
       color: white;
   }

    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: #245871;
        color: white;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 70%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }

    .nav-links a{
        opacity: 1;
        color: white;
    }
    .burger{
      display: block;
    }
}

.nav-active{
    transform: translateX(0%);
    color: white;
}

@keyframes navLinkFade{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    } to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
                    <h4>xxx</h4>    
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li class=".home-btn"><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
                <li class=".exchange-btn"><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
                <li class=".debit-btn"><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
                <li class=".crypto-btn"><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
                <li class=".stock-btn"><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="burger">    
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>

            </div>
```

Comment: first code posted was a bit faulty so I updated it.